# Type 'Script | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Script'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Script'.ts(2322)

Tags: angular

I am a newbie to Angular and I am very limited to troubleshooting code.

The class below was working in Angular 11 but I updated Angular to the latest version and afterwards, the compiler did not like  the 2 lines bolded below.  I tried the quick fix options for the first bolded line (script!: Script) and assignment assertion worked.  For the 2nd bolded line, there was no quick fix.  The error for the 2nd bolded line is "Type 'Script | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Script'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Script'.ts(2322)"

Any help would be appreciated!

```
export class MainContentComponent implements OnInit {

  **script: Script**;
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute, 
    private service: ScriptService,
    private router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      const id = params['id'];

      this.service.scripts.subscribe(scripts => {
        **this.script** = this.service.scriptById(id);
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share scriptById method?

Comment: When I hover over scriptById, the compiler pops up the following:
(method) ScriptService.scriptById(id: number): Script | undefined

Comment: scriptById(id: number){
      return this.datastore.scripts.find(x => x.id == id);
    }

Answer (score 0):

The `ScriptService's scriptById` method may return a `Script` if found or `undefined` otherwise. You are using that returned value to assign it to a variable of type `Script` hence the reporter type error.

So, there are couple of ways now.

1. Handle the case for `undefined` return.
2. Be assertive that the method will never return `undefined`.

I am sure this will depend on how you want your code to be, but below would be my approach.

```
// all the rest
this.service.scripts.subscribe(scripts => {
  const script = this.service.scriptById(id);
  if (!script) { throw new Error('...') // or log and return}
  this.script = script.
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ravi!
This resolved my strict typescript issue however, my code failed to compile because script is undefined.  Not sure what to do or try next.  Everything worked previously in Angular 11....

Answer (score 0):

```
scriptById(id: number): any {
    return this.datastore.scripts.find(x => x.id == id);
}
```

Declare return type of scriptById any as return value can be null, undefined or script.

Comment: Thank you @zainhassan!
I tried your code snippet and the project failed to compile. Id is still undefined...

Comment: which id is undefined? can you share stackblitz?